# Активити с двумя фрагментами?

Tags: android

В ВК когда открываешь любую песню можно свайпом влево или вправо открыть текст песни или сам плеер. Хочу в своем приложении реализовать такое же. А именно есть список песен при нажатии на песню чтобы открывалось активити (плеер), а при свайпе влево переходил как в плеере ВК на текста песни. Подскажите как это можно реализовать (фрагментами или как)? есть ли какие-то примеры на которые можно посмотреть?

P.S. хочется еще чтобы как в ВК внизу были кружочки показывающие пользователю что можно сделать свайп.

Пример из ВК на скринах

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это `ViewPager` насчет точек гуглить "pager indicator"

Comment: Спасибо, буду смотреть